# Deleting bulk objects in DataContext

Tags: c#, linq

Can't i delete bulk objects like

```
List<Person> prn = new List<Person>();
prn.Add(new Person { Id = "P007", name = "Andrew"});
prn.Add(new Person { Id = "P009", name = "Bernold"});
prn.Add(new Person { Id = "P010", name = "Hare"});
PersonDB.Persons.DeleteAllOnSubmit(prn);
PersonDB.SubmitChanges();
```

I receive error

```
Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [attaching](http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Understanding-AttachingDetaching-Objects-in-LINQ-to-SQL-and-in-the-Entity-Framework.aspx) the objects to the context before deleting:

```
PersonDB.Persons.AttachAll(prn, true);
```

Comment: For me AttachAll(prn,false) is working,when i set true,it throws error.